# Discord.js Welcome message shows user as a bunch of numbers instead of the actual username

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member =>{

    const welcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`A new user has joined the server, everyone welcome ${member.user}!`)

    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "welcome-channel");
    if(!channel) return;

    channel.send(welcomeEmbed)
});
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you wanted to mention them, you could make use of their ID :

```js
const welcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`A new user has joined the server, everyone welcome <@${member.id}>!`);
```

Answer (score 5):

That's because you can not mention someone inside of a title on an embed,

So what it does is it converts it into a user_id pattern, like `<@id_here>`

using a user class to mention someone works for an actual message, example:

```js
message.chanenl.send(`${message.user} hey`);
```

That would mention the user, and respond with "hey",

but like I said previously in an embed title you can't mention someone.

So the best option is to use their username:

```js
const welcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(`A new user has joined the server, everyone welcome ${member.user.username}!`);
```